# book for complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, book-recommendation

I have to read complex analysis.I have two options for books to follow.
J.B. Conway, Functions of One Complex Variable and Complex analysis by L.V. Ahlfors.Which book should I follow?

Comment: I'm voting to close as opinion-based; you've provided no context for your background, what your goals are for the reading, or any other relevant information. (-1)

Comment: Read both and compare.

Answer (score 1):

Ahlfors'book (use 3rd edition) is a classic but is hard to read ;Conway is a good readable treatment well used in courses . If you are doing this without a teacher you are safer with Conway.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both books and would recommend Ahlfors as a good tool for getting a wide variety of exercise problems. Also, see this [related MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1384391/books-on-complex-analysis-ahlfors-conway-and-lang).